# An error happened when I compile the spark1.6.1 source code

Tags: apache-spark

When I complie the spark1.6.1 source code, an error happened as follows:

```
Running org.apache.spark.JavaAPISuite
Exception in thread "Executor task launch worker-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: RpcEnv already stopped.
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.send(NettyRpcEnv.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEndpointRef.send(NettyRpcEnv.scala:516)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalBackend.statusUpdate(LocalBackend.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone knows about this issue and how to solve it please?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run the unit tests to compile Spark.

If you are using SBT, just run `build/sbt assembly`. If you are using maven, just run `build/mvn package -DskipTests`.

Comment: Hi, I saw you answered some question in https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10881, I tried git cherry-pick <commit id> but it failed with error "git cherry-pick fatal: bad revision", could you please tell me how to fix this issue so that I can pass the test when I compile the source code?

Comment: This patch cannot be applied on Spark 1.6.*. Did you change any Spark codes? Otherwise, you don't need to run tests since they have been tested.

Comment: I did not change any spark code. Then why I cannot pass the test when I complie the source code please?

Comment: There were some flaky tests. They might fail depending on environments or how the tests run.

Comment: The issue you mentioned here is not a critical one, won't affect the correctness of the results. It just may happen when you are stopping a SparkContext. You can upgrade to 2.* if you really care about it.